# using NotebookOpen with the Wolfram Engine

Tags: notebooks, free-wolfram-engine

I try to use `NotebookOpen` with the Wolfram Engine. As far as I know Wolfram Engine does not include the notebook interface, but it does include the FrontEnd functionality, so I tried

```
UsingFrontEnd[nb = NotebookOpen["path/to/notebook/code.nb", Visible->False]];
```

At first glance this seems to work, but using the `NotebookObject` with another function like `NotebookImport` fails:

```
UsingFrontEnd[
    nb = NotebookOpen["path/to/notebook/code.nb", Visible->False];
    cellsExpressions = NotebookImport[nb, _->"Expression"];
];
```

> NotebookImport::notanb: No notebook file found at NotebookObject[<< code.nb >>].

Using it with `NotebookRead` also fails:

```
UsingFrontEnd[
    nb = NotebookOpen["path/to/notebook/code.nb", Visible->False];
    cells = Cells[nb];
    NotebookRead[cells]
];
```

> ```
> {$Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed}
> ```

To me it seems that the notebook is not kept open by `NotebookOpen` when being used in the Wolfram Engine. This leads to problems as documented for example in the `NotebookRead` documentation:

> If an object is no longer valid, NotebookRead returns `$Failed`. If a list of objects is given, then `$Failed` will be returned for each of the invalid objects.

Interestingly `Cells[nb]` seems to yield the `CellObject`s associated with the notebook cells.

Is there a way to make `NotebookOpen` work with the Wolfram Engine?